# Naming convention having two targets in the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I had two target for my application. One free and other is for paid.
Now i need to add different icons for both target. Now the problem is that i can not used apple naming conventions like now i use icon_free.png and icon_paid.png. 
My Problem when i add 512px icon then will  iOS will automatically pick the correct image for each build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways.

First option: You can use apples naming conventions. Just store the icons in different sub directories. When creating the second target one suitable sub-dir was created. However, you can create a new one.

Place the files with default names in each of the directories. 
Create separated groups for them in your navigtor tree in xcode. Upon creation of the second target that should have been done anyway. So you can have both versions of the icon with the same name at different branches within your navigation tree.

Then go to the copy build settings of each target and make sure that the appropriate version is included for each target.

Second option: Alternatively give the icon (and default etc.) files different names and name them explicitely in plist.info. And plist.info then exsist for each of the targets. For plist.info xcode should have created separate files anyway. You find it on the info tab of the projedct settings close to the build obtions tab.

In general I found it is good pactice beeing neat with separate folders. After hasseling around with difficult problems when having two targets with newer apps I always have one sub-dir with all the shared resources and one for each of the targets. It makes it easier to boundle the copy and compile settings for each of the targets accordingly.

Just one more: When ever you apply changes to the bundles in this way you should delete the apps thoroughly from the simulators and test devices. If you don't then you may run into situations where the root cause is difficult to find. That is that there are old versions of some of the resources on the device. They will not be updated along with new releases. You will then have as best missing resoures on 3rd party devices and in the worst case you will chase errors and all what you try does not have an effect on the device/simulator because the locally existing resource is not being updated. Difficult to figure out.

Comment: You certainly don't want to include both versions of each icon in each app, so whether you use the same name (first option) or custom names (second option), you should definitely use the Target Membership panel of the File Inspector to ensure that only the correct icon files are included in each target.

Comment: I just creat a folder and place all icons using apple naming conventions and then add that folder in that target. By checking the options of change folder to group. but it is not showing correct images version. I had also removed the free build icon from paid version

Comment: It should do. But make sure that each of the images is added to ONE target only. So the free version of the image is added to the free target only. You can check what is actually built. You can access the app's directories on the simulator easily and you can open the *.app or *.ipa package and have a look at its contents. While we are talking about image resouces, that is probably the easiest way to check what is really happening.

Comment: Caleb is right. The target membership panel in the file inspector is probalbly a more convenient way of checking and controling which resource belongs to which target.

Comment: there was too problem in my project one the 2nd target info.plist file reference path was not relative to project folder due to which this all problem was occurring. And second my plist icon array has already some names that i had added while test, so empty the array and reenter the icons name